# Remove array from multidimentional array using id in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove array from multidimentional array using base of ID. I tried using foreach loop. But, It is not working.

Any one help me how to remove this?

Thanks.

**=> Array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11109
            [value] => Yes
            [field_id] => 234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11109
            [value] => Yes
            [field_id] => 237
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11110
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 234
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11110
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 237
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11111
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 237
        )

)
```

From this array, I want to remove array which

- field_id is 234 and value is "No" && field_id is 237 and value is
  "No".
- field_id is 234 and value is "Yes" && field_id is 237 and value is
  "Yes".

So, From this array only ID 11111 array is display otherwise all array remove from current array.

Here is my code using I tried to remove array.

```
foreach ($collection->getData() as $key => $value) {
                        if(($value['field_id'] == $ids[0] && $value['value'] == "No")){
                            echo $value['id'];
                            // exit;
                            break;
                        }
                        echo $value['field_id'];
                        echo $value['value'];
                        if(($value['field_id'] == $ids[1] && $value['value'] == "No")){
                            print_r($collection->getData()[$key]);
                            unset($collection->getData()[$key]);
                            unset($collection->getData()[$key-1]);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Is this code related to Magento Collections..?

Comment: Yes. @SudhirBastakoti

Comment: You want to remove the whole array or just the element inside of that array?

Comment: can you also include the output of your code

Comment: Whole array. @Bluetree
Output is also same like display as I mention in question

Comment: Can you also what is the value of this `$ids`

Comment: It's field_id value

Comment: I think it's `getData()`, which give a copy of the array, not reference.

Comment: so this is `$is[0]` equal to 234 and `$ids[1]` is equal to 235? Am i right?

Comment: if 234 has value of No and 237 has value of Yes. None of them would be removed?

Comment: Check this -> [Link] (https://eval.in/901014)

Answer (score 0):

Is the function `getData()` returning a copy of the array or a reference? If is is only a copy the `unset($collection->getData()[$key])` won't work.

Better you loop over the array as you do, but store all keys you want to delete in side a other array (e.g. `$keysToRemove`). When the for-each-loop is finished you start to loop the new array `$keysToRemove` containing all the keys you want to remove and remove then from array.

```
$keysToRemove = array();
$data = $collection->getData(); // copy or reference?
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if(($value['field_id'] == $ids[0] && $value['value'] == "No")){
    echo $value['id'].'<br>';
    break; // exit the loop? If you want to jump to the next element use "continue"
  }
  echo $value['field_id'].'<br>';
  echo $value['value'].'<br>';
  if(($value['field_id'] == $ids[1] && $value['value'] == "No")){
    $keysToRemove[$key]   = true;
    $keysToRemove[$key-1] = true;
  }
}

foreach(array_keys($keysToRemove) as $key){
  echo '<p>remove key '.$key.' with content <pre>'.print_r($data[$key], true).'</pre></p>';
  unset($data[$key]);
}

echo '<p>Result array is<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre></p>';
```

So you don't manipulate the array your loop use at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Multidimensional array , and copy only the values you want to it .

also , when you use break , you get out of the foreach loop completely , i don't think this is the intended behavior , use continue to skip current iteration and test the next element

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment that mentioned its a Magento Collection. I think, You could filter the ids in collection itself so that those are not fetched as part of the collection you want. Like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('your/model')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('field_id', array('nin' => array(234, 237)));
```

OR, following if your model is non-eav entity model

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('your/model')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('field_id', array('nin' => array(234, 237)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code which remove all array value which value is No

```
$cart = array(
    0 => array
    (
        'id' => 11109,
        'value' => 'Yes',
        'field_id' => 234
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        'id' => 11109,
        'value' => 'Yes',
        'field_id' => 123
    ),
    2 => array
    (
        'id' => 11110,
        'value' => 'No',
        'field_id' => 234
    ),
    3 => array
    (
        'id' => 11110,
        'value' => 'No',
        'field_id' => 237
    ),
    4 => array
    (
        'id' => 11111,
        'value' => 'No',
        'field_id' => 237
    ),
);




$found = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($cart as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['field_id'] == 234 && $data['value'] == 'No') {


        $found[$i]['id'] = $data['id'];
        $found[$i]['value'] = $data['value'];
        $found[$i]['field_id'] = $data['field_id'];
        $i++;

    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($found);
```

then Output Is:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11111
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 234
        )

)
```

Comment: Want to display just this => [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11111
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 237
        )

Comment: @RohanHapani how you want to this value? which condition?

Comment: Only field_id = 234 and value no then match condition ,

 3 => array
    (
        'id' => 11110,
        'value' => 'No',
        'field_id' => 237
    ),
    4 => array
    (
        'id' => 11111,
        'value' => 'No',
        'field_id' => 237
    ),

Comment: On 11110, There are field_id = 234 and value is "No" and field_id = 237 value is "No". So, it must be remove from array.

Comment: @RohanHapani your condition and out put result not same.

Comment: @RohanHapani [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11111
            [value] => No
            [field_id] => 237
        )

filed_value 237 and value no so ?